# MySQL Character Encodings for Connector/C

Tags: mysql, c, character-encoding

MySQL's character encoding mechanism is legendary in both it's complexity and it's opaqueness, and I have a question about how to correctly interpret string data being returned from a MySQL Connector/C query.

If my Connector/C code is set to `UTF-8` (using `mysql_set_character_set()`), will the MySQL library (and/or server) transcode data in `latin1` that's stored in the server to `UTF-8` or am I still required to use `mysql_fetch_field` on a per-field basis to determine the character set of any string data?

Answer (score 2):

Give this page a read: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html

Since `mysql_set_character_set()` works like `SET NAMES` statement, it will modify the character set that the server sends back to the client.

> SET NAMES indicates what character set the client will use to send SQL statements to the server. Thus, SET NAMES 'cp1251' tells the server, “future incoming messages from this client are in character set cp1251.” It also specifies the character set that the server should use for sending results back to the client. (For example, it indicates what character set to use for column values if you use a SELECT statement.)

Comment: Hence, there is no need to do anything "per-field".  During a `SELECT`, all text columns are transcoded from the column's charset to the charset specified by `mysql_set_character_set()`.

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely improbable to have collisions between properly encoded strings in Latin1 and UTF-8.  You can check proper UTF-8 encoding and assume Latin1 for badly encoded strings and convert them yourself on a case by case basis. Assuming correct configuration and encoding everywhere is risky.